# Find all the values of x, for which the series converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^∞ (x^2/(x^2+4))^n$

I did try to use the ratio test and I ended up with
$| x^2/(x^2+4)|<1$

I don't have any idea what to do after this, how do I solve for x?

Comment: $\frac{x^2}{x^2+4}<1$ is always true, because $x^2<x^2+4$.

Comment: It was never stated that $x$ must be real. If it can be complex the solution is slightly more interesting. Maybe OP should clarify?

Answer (score 2):

$x^2$ is positive

$$x^2<x^2+4$$

$$0<4$$

Converges for all x

Answer (score 1):

Let $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\xi^{n}$ converges iff $|\xi| < 1.$
Since
$$0 \leq \frac{x^{2}}{x^{2} + 4} < 1$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, it follows that
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\dfrac{x^{2}}{x^{2} + 4})^{n}$ converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 0):

Start simplifying the problem defining $y=\frac{x^2}{x^2+4}$ and use the fact that $y<1$ (since, for any $x$, $x^2<x^2+4$). So $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^∞ \Big(\frac{x^2}{x^2+4}\Big)^n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^∞ y^n=\frac{y}{1-y}=\frac{x^2}{4}$$